# is there a function to connect two sets of points with a line within matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm doing a paper where I have 2 sets of points,  one is experimental and the other is calculated, and to compare them I have to connect each equivalent point by a simple line and plot it.

for exemple, the experimental is the base of the line and the calculated is the end of the line

the datapoints are stored in a pandas dataframe and I used matplotlib to plot them

The code is as follows

```
oil_xp = pd.DataFrame('metanol':[3.9, 6.5, 9.2, 16.1], 'acido':[96, 88.15, 80.5, 64.])
oil_sim= pd.DataFrame('metanol':[5.0, 7.2, 9.3, 16.6], 'acido':[95., 87.7, 80.3, 63.82] )
```

with a regular plot,it looks like this

note: there is a missing data point here and you may notice some data error, but I had a problem with the data and had to estimate it

[the plot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYyhE.png)

What I need is to connect each oil_sim point with oil_xp point by a straight line and maintain the regular connection between same dataframe

Comment: This is a programming question. Add sone code and desired result to your question. Otherwise it’s too vague and broad to answer

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide an example data frame , what you have tried and what is the expected result.

Based on your description, I came up with a data.frame, 2 columns and plotted them like below. If it is different in your scenario, please provide more information:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'experimental':np.random.uniform(0,20,5),
'calculated':np.random.uniform(0,20,5)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.T,'o')
ax.plot(df.T,linewidth = 0.5, linestyle = '--',color="gray")
```

[image]

Comment: the plot would be between two distinct dataframes, df_experimental, df_calculated,but the behaviour I needed were these lines connecting each related point

Comment: hey @felipekreftbatista, help us help you, provide this information in your question.

Comment: ...and a solution to my problem just came by: I can do several plots in the same figure,   overlappin the results to get the image I need